# getting an exception in sqlite database operation methods in android

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I am getting an error in my sqlite db operation class.

The error is this : java.lang.IllegalStateException: attempt to re-open an already-closed object:

My code is as follows :

```
public void incrementViewCountForShow(String showId){

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    showViews(showId);

    String query = "UPDATE " + TABLE_SHOWS + " SET " + COLUMN_SHOW_VIEWS + "=" + COLUMN_SHOW_VIEWS + "+1" + " WHERE " + COLUMN_SHOW_ID + "=" + showId ; 

    db.rawQuery(query, null);

    showViews(showId);

    db.close();

}

private void showViews(String showId){

    boolean isFirst = true;
    StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    String query = "SELECT " + COLUMN_SHOW_NAME_EN + "," + COLUMN_SHOW_VIEWS + " FROM " + TABLE_SHOWS + " where " + COLUMN_SHOW_ID + "=" + showId;
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);

    if (cursor != null) {

        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {

            strBuilder.append(cursor.getString(0));

        }
    }

    cursor.close();
    db.close();
}
```

What is the reason for this error? How to fix this?

** can't we do two operations in the same method ? (read from db twice)

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is the reason for this error?

You are calling `close()` on the `SQLiteDatabase` several times.

> How to fix this?

Do not call `close()` on the `SQLiteDatabase` several times. In fact, you should not call `close()` on the `SQLiteDatabase` at all. Instead, call `close()` on the `SQLiteOpenHelper`, and only do that when you are *completely done* with the `SQLiteOpenHelper`.

Also, as Der Golem notes, use `execSQL()`, not `rawQuery()`, for SQL statements that do not return a result set.

Comment: thanks for the quick reply. I created the db and implemented the all the db access methods in the same class. what would be the best way to use sqlite db in android?

Comment: @chathura2020: There is no single "best" way. But do not close your `SQLiteOpenHelper` (and, hence, its `SQLiteDatabase`) until you are completely done with it.

Answer (score 2):

`db.rawQuery(query, null);` is only used for **queries** (SELECT). For **commands** (INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, CREATE TABLE, ...), use `db.execSQL(query, null);`

And remove the `db.close();` line in `showViews()`